# Deceleration effect

Tags: sound-design, replication, electronic-music, production-sound

I've been trying for a while to create this sound which appears in many dubstep song, it is kind of a deceleration effect which Im sure is very simple, though I am not really sure how to make it.

The sound appears on this song in the minute 1:00.

Answer (score 1):

The descending texture (one of several layers I hear at 1:00) sounds vaguely like a stutter effect with a decreasing playback rate.

The source audio matters a lot when working with stutter effects, and they're typically created by experimenting with an existing corpus of samples. In this case, it sounds like the repeating fragment is a sine oscillator alternating with a spectrally rich "scrape" sound.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like he put a gate on the sound and then a tape delay.  Both can be found in dBlue Glitch 2.